# Eclipse RCP with google Windowbuilder pro

Tags: java, eclipse, desktop-application

Can I use Eclipse RCP framework with google's window builder pro for desktop application development.

I also want to know more about Eclipse RCP, what are the advantages when comapared to swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use WindowBuilder Pro for Eclipse RCP development. Window Builder Pro has great support for SWT, JFace, and Eclipse RCP specific stuff like Views and Perspectives for example you can create perspectives in visual editor.

For second questions
You can directly compare Swing and Eclipse RCP, Swing equivalent is SWT, and they have comparable features. SWT has better OS native widgets look.

SWT is set of widgets that you can use. On top of SWT JFace is built- JFace is set of high level frameworks for MVC, wizards, databinding, working with table/treeview,combos ...

On top of SWT and JFace is Eclipse RCP is built which provides application framework for plugins, with support for extensions, perspectives/views,actions, menus, and basically for extendability.

Answer (score 1):

As your first question, yes, WindowBuilder Pro can create SWT code.

As for the second, there are a lot of comparisons on the pros and cons of Swing vs RCP, and the core verdict is that It Depends. Personally I would reccomend going thr RCP route for any major work, but keep in mind that it's a complete stack and not just a widget toolkit, and the things you will need to learn are correspondingly more.